# Magento2 get group product child that was added to basket

Tags: magento2, event-observer

When adding a grouped product to the basket you actually add a child product not the parent product.

We are hooking into this event: `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` but the product returned by that is the grouped product which so it has no price and the data is incorrect for our purpose.

This is the Observer snippet...

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $this->intileryAnalyticsData->log('int_product_add_to_basket');
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getData('product');

        ...
}
```

How can I get a list of the children that were added to the basket? Just to be clear I want the list of simple products that were added to the basket.

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 2):

We can get the associated products.

```
if ($product->getTypeId() ===
       \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped::TYPE_CODE) 
{
     $childProductCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($product);
}
```